# VBA to Move Files From Directory Based on Filename Length

Tags: vba, directory

We recently imported > 100,000 .tif files to a directory on our shared drive. All of these files *should* have the same naming convention: 0123456789.tif ("10 digits followed by extension .tif"). Most do, but a good handful do not. There are some that are either greater than 14 characters (10 for filename + 4 for extension), or they are less than 14 characters.

Is there a way to basically say:

"If in directory x and length(filename) <> 14 characters, then move to directory y"

(where directory y is just some other folder)?

Thank you much.

Comment: look here and modify: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/139724

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Dir()` Function to list all the files, and the `Name` operator to move the files

Something like this should work

```
Dim srcDir as String,dstDir as String,f as String
srcDir="C:\"
dstDir="D:\"
f=Dir(srcDir)
Do While f<>""
  If Len(f)<>14 Then Name srcDir & "\" & f As dstDir & "\" & f
  f=Dir()
Loop
```

Comment: You got it, that was perfect. Thank you